# Strategy or Command pattern?

Tags: c#, java, .net, design-patterns, architecture

Assuming I have a list of financial transactions, I have a need to execute a list of validation rules against those transactions.  An example would be I have a transaction to purchase a product, however first I need to validate that the account in the transaction has enough available funds, that the product is not sold out etc.  As a result of these many rules the transaction will be marked as rejected, as well as an error code should be specified.

Naturally I am thinking towards fronting my rules with an interface, allowing the executing code to roll through the rules executing each one until the first one rejects the transaction.

Each rule will require to be configured with parameters (ex. ValidateMinimumBalance will need to know that minimumBalance = 30).  The result of a rule executing can be as simple as settings the rejection code on the transaction object, and the error code; or it can be as complicated as automatically modifying multiple other properties of the transaction.

My basic understanding of design patterns points to me either Strategy or Command patterns, but I am not entirely sure which one is better suited for this scenario.

Command Pattern

1. Each command will implement some sort of IValidate interface
2. The constructor of the command will take an instance of the transaction as the receiver in order to be able to read/validate the transaction as well as modify aspects of it.  The constructor will also take an array of key/value pairs as parameters for the validation logic.

When I try to picture how the Strategy Pattern fits this scenario it looks very similar.  In most examples the strategy is a simple object with a single method, however in my case the strategy will need a reference to the transaction as well as validation parameters.

Comment: If you think these rules will be something that will be changed often or business users will need to access them, a rules engine is also a viable alternative. You can look at JBoss Drools or IBM's iLog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strategy is more used to swap out algorithms, its not really used for chaining validations.  If you are going to have a pattern where you have one validation per type then you could use the strategy, if you are finding your having to use multiple validators, or the need to reuse validators.  I think you are going to have to either find a new way to do it (aka COR) or within your strategy use the COR.

---

I actually would answer other.  I think a combination [chain of responsibility pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx) and the [composite pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx),  or [decorator for validators](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx) is much more suited for your needs.

Typing up an example implementation now.. but at a high level

**Chain of Responsiblity**
The design would revolve around something like:

```
abstract class Handler
 {
   protected Handler next;
   
   public Handler(Handler h){
      this.next = h;
   }
   public abstract bool Validate(Request request); 
   public abstract void Handle(Request request);
}

class CoreLogic: Handler
{   
   public CoreLogic(Handler handle) : base(handle){

   }
   public override void Validate(Request request){
         return True
   }
   public override void Handle(Request request){
        if(this.Validate(request)){
            if(next!= null){
              next.Handle(request);
           }
        }

   }
}

class ValidBalance: Handler
{   
   public ValidBalance(Handler handle) : base(handle){

   }
   public override void Validate(Request request){
        return True
   }
   public override void Handle(Request request){
        if(this.Validate(request)){
            if(next!= null){
              next.Handle(request);
           }
        }
        
    }
}

class MainApp
{
   static void Main(){
       Handler h = new ValidateBalance( new CoreLogic(null));
       h.Handle(new Request());

   }
}
```

---

Other useful links:

[Chain of Responsiblity wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

Comment: I was about to suggest the chain of responsibility too. Another link here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Comment: why do you feel that chain of responsibility is better in this case as opposed to the command pattern?  The main difference I see (unless I'm missing the point) is that with the command the invoker will be responsible for looping through the commands and executing each one.  With chain of responsibility it seems that this will happen automatically.

Comment: the command pattern is an abstraction tool, is more designed to detach the process of executing a command from a receiver.. IMHO i think its more of a design to be used when keeping separation from a UI

Comment: fair enough.  In my case all validators have a priority, basically dictating which should be called first in the chain.  I will also be constructing these objects dynamically as not all will be applicable to all types of transactions.  It seems in order to create the chain through the constructor I would have to start with creating the last objects first.  Is that a fair assessment?  Or instead of using the constructor to chain I could do what James suggested below.

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to picture how the Strategy Pattern fits this scenario it looks very similar.

Similar?  It should look identical.

The distinction is one of how the context and delegation works.  In principle a **Command** is the "active" agent.  A **Strategy** is injected into some active agent. That distinction is pretty subtle.

It barely changes the design.  What does change is the expectation.

Command objects (more-or-less) stand alone.  They're built to do their work, and then they can vanish.  No one cares about them any more.  Perhaps they also use the **Memento** pattern, and have some future life, but perhaps not.

Strategy objects (more-or-less) live with the object into which they're injected.  A Strategy would be part of some larger object, and could be replaced by a different implementation without breaking or changing anything else.

But the essential interface is largely the same.

> In most examples the strategy is a simple object with a single method,

Those are poor examples.

> however in my case the strategy will need a reference to the transaction as well as validation parameters.

Not unusual.  Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @S,Lott, so it seems that I could accomplish the same thing with both.  The difference would be that with the command I would instantiate each one, passing the transaction and validation parameters as part of the constructor.  Then looping through the commands and calling Validate.  With the strategy I would create an instance passing the validation parameters into the constructor.  However the transaction itself is likely to be the parameter to the Validat(transaction) method.  Unless I am missing your point, the main difference seems that the command holds a reference to the receiver.

Comment: I actually like this answer more, Why does it only have one up vote? Is there something wrong with this explanation?

Answer (score 1):

A Strategy would be something use to 'parameterize' a Command (telling it how *parts* of the operation should be executed).

Answer (score 0):

> but I am not entirely sure which one
>   is better suited for this scenario

Neither :)
I strongly recommend to look at [Interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern). Actually your validator rules are just predicates formulated for your transactions. It's quite possible that soon you will need to combine these rules with AND, OR, NOT, etc.