# Refactor with Strategy Pattern. In Ruby

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, activerecord, refactoring, strategy-pattern

Heads up!  In the below example, using a pattern is probably overkill... however, if I were extending this to count genres, count the members in a given band, count the number of fans, count the number of venues played, count the number of records sold, count the number of downloads for a specific song etc... it seems like there could be a ton of stuff to count.

**The Goal**:

To create a new function that chooses the correct counting function based on the input.

**The Example**:

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs
  has_many :artists, through: :songs

  def song_count
    self.songs.length
  end

  def artist_count
    self.artists.length
  end

end
```

P.S. If you are also a curious about this question, you may find this other question (unfortunately answered in C#) to be helpful as a supplemental context. [Strategy or Command pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514985/strategy-or-command-pattern) ...

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, it seems?

Comment: In this particular example I suggest a [counter cache](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache).

Comment: What about just `hiphop = Genre.new; hiphop.songs.count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby you can implement a strategy pattern quite easily using an (optional) block (assuming it's still unused).

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs
  has_many :artists, through: :songs

  def song_count(&strategy)
    count_using_strategy(songs, &strategy)
  end

  def artist_count(&strategy)
    count_using_strategy(artists, &strategy)
  end

  private

  def count_using_strategy(collection, &strategy)
    strategy ||= ->(collection) { collection.size }
    strategy.call(collection)
  end
end
```

The above code defaults to using the `size` strategy. If you ever want to use a specific strategy in a specific scenario you can simply provide the strategy alongside the call.

```
genre = Genre.last
genre.song_count # get the song_count using the default #size strategy
# or provide a custom stratigy
genre.song_count { |songs| songs.count } # get the song_count using #count
genre.song_count { |songs| songs.length } # get the song_count using #length
```

If you need to re-use some strategies more often you could save them in a constant or variable:

```
LENGTH_STRATEGY = ->(collection) { collection.length }

genre.artist_count(&LENGTH_STRATEGY)
```

Or create a specific class for them if they are more complicated (currently overkill):

```
class CollectionStrategy
  def self.to_proc # called when providing the class as a block argument
    ->(collection) { new(collection).call }
  end

  attr_reader :collection

  def initialize(collection)
    @collection = collection
  end
end

class LengthStrategy < CollectionStrategy
  def call
    collection.length
  end
end

genre.artist_count(&LengthStrategy)
```

Comment: Almost anything is possible, but what you're asking is more about meta-programming then the strategy pattern. What did you imagine the usage to be? Something like: `genre.count(:songs)`? Or simply `genre.count` where it expects the the collection to be given through standard input. Note that in this last one usage in a Rails server is complicated since only the server host can provided standard input.

Comment: this is very helpful! You've helped me clarify my intention:

For example, "What would you like to count?" is printed to the screen...

The user could type in "songs by Korsakov"... and a regex would determine that Korsakov is the object and the program would 'know' songs are the collection.

or "concerts performed by Korsakov", or "students of Korsakov"

Perhaps we have a function that identifies keywords: songs, concerts, students, and also artists (something like ||=) and then uses a single function/magic method as the strategy.  Regardless, thank you for the feedback!

Comment: something like count_anything_in_the_object(object, the_anything) -- also my apologies.  I feel like half the problem of being a novice is not being able to articulate what you mean.  Seeing your answers is great though, because it's helping me have a better sense of where some concepts begin and others end.

Comment: @AdamWeissman I'll extend the answer later today (and delete this reply). I currently don't have the time to fully answer your addition requirements. I've got one more question though. Since you inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` I assume that this concerns a Rails application and that a user has to provide the input through a web request, rather than the standard input.

Comment: @3limini4t0r many thanks for your help, but please don't worry about writing it out... there is no larger application.  I was using this as an example to explore a mechanic.  I'm grateful for your help as I now realize I must dive into metaprogramming!